# Mapping JSON object(Set type) to Hibernate entity

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jpa

I am able to insert json objects to my entity, but having issue with one field example `serial_id(bigint, default=0)` which gets incremented by 1 automatically while insert if I don't pass the field with value. It should insert 0 which is happening sometimes, not always

My Json is a Set of objects. The entity class is as below :

```
public class Sales extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

   @Type(type = “jsonb”)
   @Column(columnDefinition = “jsonb”, name = “sales_target”)
   private Set<SalesTarget> salesTarget = null;

   @column <- mapped to column
   private Long serial_id;
}
```

The SalesTarget entity is as below:

```
public class SalesTarget implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  private String teamLeader;
  private int salesVolume;
  private Long serialId;

}
```

the service method is `@transactional`, In debug mode `serialId` is `0`, but inserts 1 to DB column. Please help me!!!

Comment: Resolved for me...